# How to detect duplicates in the results of lambda functions?

Tags: c#, lambda, logic, operators, logical-operators

We are working with a rule engine that is based on lambda functions. Each function is instantiated with type:

```
Func<Term, bool>
```

Every function consumes an object of type Term and returns a boolean.
Term is a collection of features like so:

```
public class Term
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int SomeCount { get; set; }
}
```

The functions define some conditions on these Terms. For example:

```
Func<Term, bool> function = t => t.Age >= 18 && t.Name == "Tom";
Func<Term, bool> function = t => t.Price >= 26 || t.Price < 3200;
...
```

Given a set of these functions, is there a way to detect if more than one functions return true for any specific term? In other words, is there a way to check if such functions are non-injective? Brute forcing every possible term is no option of course.

I can't work with a given term. I have a set of these functions and I want to know if there COULD BE a term for which more than one function returns true.

EDIT:
I realize that I would have to parse some statements and do a lot of hard coded expressions in order to unify the statements for each variable, but is this even possible? I am having trouble especially with the ||-operator.

There would have to be a way to check if two functions that both return true for any specific term.

Comment: Could you please show an example, what are you expecting? Can functions return different results for the equal terms? What is the troubles with `||` operator?

Comment: Do you want to test your functions, without applying it to data ? Like to test if "Price < 10" and "Price >10" is counterwise exclusive ? Testing for one specific term is easy. Just execute it. For 'any possible term" could get difficult.

Comment: Yes. I want to test it for any possible term. I want to detect duplicates, or rather "intersections" without brute forcing every possible term. I know that it gets complicated and it would be a lot of parsing overhead. I just want to know if it's even possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Save your functions in a list or in an array. Then you can check via LINQ if more than one function returns true:

```
Func<Term, bool>[] functions = new Func<Term, bool>[]
 {
 t => t.Age >= 18 && t.Name == "Tom",
 t => t.Price >= 26 || t.Price < 3200
 };
Term yourTerm = new Term();
int amountFunctionsReturningTrue = functions.Count(f => f(yourTerm));
if(amountFunctionsReturningTrue > 1)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("More than one function returned true");
 }
```

Comment: Yes. But in this example I have a specific term. I want to detect duplicates for any specific term. I think I wasn't clear enough

Comment: I agree that you weren't clear enough. If you want to check if a function always returns true, independently to which instance of `Term` it is applied (like your second example), I guess you will need expression trees.

Comment: No, I don't want that either. I can't work with a given term. I have a set of these functions and I want to know if there is a term for which more than one function returns true.

Comment: @Ipsider: I guess also for that the solution will involve expression trees. @Pavel Anikhouski: With `Any()` you will check for `>= 1` instead of `> 1`

Comment: I am handling my lambda functions with expression trees in the database. That is not helping the case, it is just another form of representing the logical expressions